# Trouble with single and double quotes

Tags: php

I have a form that is being output to a third party and using stripslashes on my POSTS has worked fine for review while still on form page, but once it is submitted, anything after a double quote gets dropped and if there are single quotes then I still see single backslashes. I cannot figure out the right setup to allow for both single and double quotes to be used in a text input and then return correct to be sent to SalesForce.

entry example of two fields:

```
  <label for="subject">Subject Line:<span>*</span> <span class="addParenth"> (Summarize your issue in one sentence)</span></label>
                    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" cols="60" rows="2"  required data-rule-maxlength="100"></textarea>
                    <div id="charNumSub"></div>
  <label for="description">Description:<span>*</span></label>
                    <textarea id="description" name="dd_description" cols="60" rows="5" required data-rule-maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                    <div id="charNum"></div>
```

form then loads to next page:

```
  $subject  =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
  $dd_description   =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['dd_description']);
```

review on page:

```
  Subject:<strong> '. stripslashes($subject) .'</strong><br />
  Description:<strong> '. stripslashes($dd_description) .'</strong><br />
```

So I continue to get the review to work for the double quotes but not the single quotes but the double quotes drop anything after input when sent to SalesForce.

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It was there but not visible since the question wasn't properly formatted.

Comment: Where are the backslashes coming from in the first place? If you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled in your php.ini, get rid of it (it's been removed completely in recent PHP versions).

Comment: html doesn't uses blackslashses for escaping. stripslashes is NOT the inverse of htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Thanks for formatting that properly!

Comment: *but the double quotes drop anything after input when sent to SalesForce* - What does that mean exactly? Can you give an example of what is happening and what you would expect to happen?

Comment: I used striplslashes because I want the review page to show the provided text in the subject and description properly. And this works for the doubt quotes but not something entered in single quotes. I get the review page to display what they enter, but SalesForce does not get anything after a double quote. Unfortunately I am picking up where another developer left off and this is all way over my head and the pieces are all in place just not quite working the best way. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have no idea what the magic quotes is.

Comment: @Mike when I enter something in double quotes, my review page looks fine  example= Here comes a sentence in quotes "This is a test",  shows up as= Here comes a sentence in quotes "This is a test" in my review page, but in SalesForce they are showing= Here comes a sentence in quotes \

Comment: And for the review page, when anything is entered in single quotes I get the backslash.

Comment: @GregLang I am unfamiliar with SalesForce. Do they have any sort of documentation anywhere for what you are trying to do?

Comment: You need to use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to undo the htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @Ali in lieu of stripslashes or in lieu of the htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: In the place of stripslashes as I'm assuming you are trying to get the original input when you use stripslashes right?